# Reading data in .txt file excluding header and footers

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I have a .txt file that looks like:

```
abcd this is the header
more header, nothing here I need
***********
column1    column2
=========  =========
  12.4       A
  34.6       mm
  1.3        um
=====================
footer, nothing that I need here
***** more text ******
```

I am trying to read the data in the columns, each into it's own list, col1 = [12.4, 34.6, 1.3] and col2 = ['A', 'mm', 'um'].

This is what I have so far, but the only thing that is returned when I run the code is 'None':

```
def readfile():
    y = sys.argv[1]

    z = open(y)
    for line in z:

        data = False
        if data == True:
            toks = line.split()
            print toks

        if line.startswith('=========  ========='):
            data = True
            continue

        if line.startswith('====================='):
            data = False
            break
print readfile()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where's the rest of your code where you `return`, or parse the line?

Comment: Please include the entire relevant code, and use proper indentation.

Comment: The `data = False` line should be at the end! Not just before `if data = True:`

Comment: You have not included all the relevant code. Please include code starting from the line containing `def <functionName>`, ending with the line containing `return <stuff>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this.

One way involves:

1. Reading the file into lines
2. From the lines read, find the indices of the lines that have contain the column header delimiter (as this also matches against the footer header).
3. Then, store the data between these lines.
4. Parse these lines by splitting them based on whitespace and storing them into their respective columns.

**Like this:**

```
with open('data.dat', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    #This gets the limits of the lines that contain the header / footer delimiters
    #We can use the Column header delimiters double-time as the footer delimiter:
    #`=====================` also matches against this.
    #Note, the output size is supposed to be 2. If there are lines than contain this delimiter, you'll get problems
    limits = [idx for idx, data in enumerate(lines) if '=========' in data]

    #`data` now contains all the lines between these limits
    data = lines[limits[0]+1:limits[1]] 

    #Now, you can parse the lines into rows by splitting the line on whitespace
    rows = [line.split() for line in data]

    #Column 1 has float data, so we convert the string data to float
    col1 = [float(row[0]) for row in rows]

    #Column 2 is String data, so there is nothing further to do
    col2 = [row[1] for row in rows]

    print col1, col2
```

This outputs (from your example):

```
[12.4, 34.6, 1.3] #Column 1
['A', 'mm', 'um'] #Column 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The method you are adopting might not be very efficient, but it is a bit buggy & hence your erroneous data extraction.

You need to trigger the boolen i.e. `data` right after `line.startswith('=========  =========')` & thus, till then it should be kept `False`.

Thereon, your data will get extracted until the `line.startswith('=====================')`.

Hope I got you right.

```
def readfile():
    y = sys.argv[1]
    toks = []
    with open(y) as z:
        data = False

        for line in z:

            if line.startswith('=========  ========='):
                data = True
                continue

            if line.startswith('====================='):
                data = False
                break

            if data:
                toks.append(line.split())
                print toks
    col1, col2 = zip(*toks) # Or just simply, return zip(*toks)
    return col1, col2

print readfile()
```

The `with` statement is more pythonic & better than `z = open(file)`.

Comment: If you specifically want a `list` though, you can always cast the `tuple` into a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many lines of header/footer the file has, then you can use this method.

```
path = r'path\to\file.csv'
header = 2
footer = 2
buffer = []

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for _ in range(header):
        f.readline()

    for _ in range(footer):
        buffer.append(f.readline())

    for line in f:
        buffer.append(line)
        line = buffer.pop(0)

        # do stuff to line
        print(line)
```

Skipping header lines are trivial I had problems skipping footer lines since:

- I didn't want to change the file in any way manually
- I didn't want to count the number of lines in the file
- I didn't want to store the entire file in a list (ie, readlines()) **^**

**^ Note**: If you don't mind storing the entire file in memory, you can use this:

```
path = r'path\to\file.csv'
header = 2
footer = 2

with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines()[header:-footer if footer else None]:
        # do stuff to line
        print(line)
```